# A problem about LM310N

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have aquestion about LM310. Forgive me because I am not a native English speaker，I used Google translation.

The internal resistance of my input signal terminal is very large, about gigaohm level, and the input impedance of LM310N is very large, so I chose this voltage follower chip. I read the data sheet and it has already been connected as a voltage follower internally.

I have a single power supply. For power supply, no matter whether the input signal is connected or not, the output of the voltage follower is the power supply voltage. In addition, I use a 7.4 V voltage 280 mA power supply.

I would like to ask everyone why I am in this situation.

Comment: Can you [Edit] to post your schematic?

Comment: Also link to the pdf data sheet for the 310.

Comment: LM310 is bipolar part with input bias currents specified in nA level typical, it is not "very large" when talking about GOhm range input impedance. You need to check exact numbers or use CMOS input amplifier which can have input currents many orders of magnitude lower.

Comment: The LM310 is 30 years old ands is almost obsolete. Use a newer opamp that has Fet or Cmos inputs.